# Use a Pivot Table to summarise a ledger

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, libreoffice-calc

I have a basic ledger in the format:

```
Credit Currency | Credit Amount | Debit Currency | Debit Amount 
================+===============================================
LTC             |           0.4 | GBP            |          £100
BTC             |          0.02 | LTC            |          0.15
```

There's a few more columns but they are not of interest.

What I'm looking to get is a pivot table that summarizes the ledger but it is really stumping me. I can get a summary of the Credit Amounts by Credit Currency and the Debit Amount by Debit Currency easily enough, but how do you link the 2 together i.e. show a running total of 'Credits - Debits'?

I'm currently trying to do this with Google Sheets, but answers that only apply to Excel or LibreOffice Calc are welcome. If I have to use an alternative to Sheets then I will.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, a debit and a credit are both shown on the same line, but these are two different transactions.  The data should look like this instead.

```
Currency | Amount
=========+===========
LTC      |        0.4
GBP      |      -£100
BTC      |       0.02
LTC      |      -0.15
```

If the data cannot be rearranged, then you'll have to treat the data as two different tables, one for credits and one for debits.  The two would need to be combined somehow before creating a pivot table.